# Benefits of lighting a lamp using different oils

Tags: belief, rituals, worship

Deeparadhana (worshiping God by lighting a lamp) is an ancient practice in our country. We start any pooja by lighting a lamp. It is said that a lamp lit using cow ghee is the best. Sesam oil is used for daily deeparadhana in houses. But recently many astrologers have been advising people to light diyas using different oils like castor oil, Mahua flower oil, mustard oil, coconut oil etc., They are advising to use different number of wicks and different types of wicks too.

**My questions** -

1. Is using different oils and different wicks for lighting lamps justified in any of our scriptures?
2. If yes, What are the benefits of using particular oils in deeparadhana?