# Is there specific timing or general rules to follow while lighting diyas?

Tags: rituals, puja

I would like to know, whether any scriptures mentions about rules of diya lighting. Like

1. When and in which direction to light a lamp (Kuthu vilakku or Panch mukha lamp) - any specification like it has to be lit only during partiular prahar (early morning or evening)
2. What is the significance of fuel used to light lamp - some use ginger oil, ghee, coconut oil and mixture of several oils - why different oils are used
3. Can we light single kuthu vilakku or it must always be lit in even numbers (2).

On the whole, where can I find details about what shastra or vedic scripts say about significance of lighting a lamp?.

Thanks

Comment: The timing depends on the purpose u are lighting the deepas for..During Pujas for eg deepas should be lightened before starting the Puja and should be placed on the left side of the Deity..also Ghee is the first preference for the oil but other oils like seasme,mustard etc are also not disallowed.

Comment: I asked a [similar](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15880/benefits-of-lighting-a-lamp-using-different-oils) question. The lamp is generally put facing north and east directions. Single wick is not allowed in worship. A lamp single wick is lit when someone passes away. Timing: Before starting the pooja. If you are asking about sandhya deepas, it is two and a half ghadiyas i.e; 1 hour before sun set. Ghee is given the first preference. Ginger oil or Gingelly oil? Many use Gingelly oil and Ginger shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for pujas,we have to use 9 wicks which shows the presence of all deities and for sandhya kal 1 or 3 wicks can be used.1 wick for lord Ganesha,and 3 wicks for Lord Shiv,Vishnu & devis. Strictly we are not allowed to put 2 wicks  "Dvidivya Balabalam" means always there will be a fight b/w the husband & wife who staying in that family.Regarding this 4 wicks,which is also not allowed because it cause the arise of diseases.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! You should cite sources.